# Print lines where any word begins and ends with the same letter in linux

Tags: regex, grep

I have input  like

```
sie%Qu7s Kuux"oh9 ohc9ahG% hoe8Toh: Eix*ohd1 doh:bo2U Cu0doo|t zo`L9xaW
fie5Du[h Phe8aid# Opu&fai5 ieZ<aek6 hu4ga&Di Oose}p1p aiD@oos2 nu-a1Fub
ahqu5To/ ahtie[H3 ioK&u5Ai nei1Za#d poo_Th9r gu|aGh7h uZ%io2ah IeNah&v7
eif\e8AE Ieb,ing4 reph1oW* eeSh'ee8 Ah+ei4ai Oi0Ca,vu Esh1xe?e Wei&k4ic
ue5OhQu. aaf-i8uP eedae%T5 sei?M9Pu ieH[oh2l ieh~ah8A aev"oo9A Ohf"i8de
Foh:x2zi aLoo'qu2 Ia6aig-e La{vie1E IeFoh{cI Au_h7Hee Se)f4ebi Cah$yu7m
```

where each word in the column constitutes a password ،  i am trying to print lines where where any word begins and ends with the same letter , with this we do not distinguish between uppercase and lowercase letters

i know with command  grep i can do this

```
cat passwords.txt | grep -e ' \([A-Z]\)......\1 ' -e ' \([a-z]\)......\1 '
```

but here the word will start and end only with same latter (uppercase or lowercase letters)  ,
like

```
Foh:x2zi aLoo'qu2 Ia6aig-e La{vie1E IeFoh{cI Au_h7Hee Se)f4ebi Cah$yu7m
```

expected output

```
    eif\e8AE Ieb,ing4 reph1oW* eeSh'ee8 Ah+ei4ai Oi0Ca,vu Esh1xe?e Wei&k4ic
    sie%Qu7s Kuux"oh9 ohc9ahG% hoe8Toh: Eix*ohd1 doh:bo2U Cu0doo|t zo`L9xaW
    ue5OhQu. aaf-i8uP eedae%T5 sei?M9Pu ieH[oh2l ieh~ah8A aev"oo9A Ohf"i8de
    Foh:x2zi aLoo'qu2 Ia6aig-e La{vie1E IeFoh{cI Au_h7Hee Se)f4ebi Cah$yu7m
    ahqu5To/ ahtie[H3 ioK&u5Ai nei1Za#d poo_Th9r gu|aGh7h uZ%io2ah IeNah&v7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GNU grep:

```
grep -i -P '(?<!\S)(\S)(?:\S*\1)?(?!\S)' passwords.txt
```

The `-i` option turns on case insensitivity, `-P` turns on PCRE flavor (supports lookbehinds/lookaheads).

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/kQsXL7/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```perl
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S                       non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S                       non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S*                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ") (0 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \1                       what was matched by capture \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S                       non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program. Written and tested with GNU `awk`, should work in any `awk`.

```
awk '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if(tolower(substr($i,1,1))==tolower(substr($i,length($i)))){
      print
      next
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, going through all the fields(columns) in all the lines and comparing their 1st and last values(each field's) if they are equal then print that line and move on to next line and so on.

---

---

***Bonus solution:*** Just a little tweak of above solution, in case you have GNU `awk` then use `IGNORECASE` and you could shorten above to following code then.

```
awk -v IGNORECASE="1" '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if(substr($i,1,1)==substr($i,length($i))){
      print
      next
    }
  }
}
' Input_file
```